# Efficient way to count members of same group

Tags: sql, pandas, algorithm

Lets say that I have a dataset of people who are members of groups:

```
Group ID | Person ID
1          1
2          1
2          2
3          1
3          3
```

For each person, I want to count the number of distinct people who are in at least one of the same groups (including themselves):

```
Person ID | Distinct Co-Members
1           3
2           2
3           2
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this count other than joining the above dataset on itself with a key of the Group ID?

Comment: pandas or sql ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a self-join and group by:

```
select t1.personid, count(distinct t2.personid)
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.groupid = t2.groupid
group by t1.personid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e5a4a98938c3f40f0d5783af9892d9d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nunique`

```
df.merge(df,on='GroupID').groupby('PersonID_x')['PersonID_y'].nunique().reset_index()
Out[170]: 
   PersonID_x  PersonID_y
0           1           3
1           2           2
2           3           2
```